# Why is my Prestashop forgot password not working

Tags: prestashop-1.7

The Forgot Password link in our Prestashop 1.7 site is not working. After setting the admin email on the following, we still do not receive any reset password

```
Shop Parameters > Contact > Stores tab: <set the admin email>
```

When I try to send a test email using the links below, I receive the test email

```
Advanced Parameters > Email > Test Your Email Configuration
```

I am able to receive a test email from the admin email address I set on Shop Parameters. So that means, the email sending is working.

On the Forgot Password page, I entered my email and clicked the Send Reset Link. I checked the Inbox and Spam and did not see any reset link email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you check that you have a mail template for sending forgotten emails in the corresponding language folder?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue (Prestashop 1.7.2.5) From what I can find, if your email setup is configured as PHP, Password Reset works only occasionally depending on email account you are sending to.

It is better to configure your email setup for SMTP. Due to the high amounts of spam being circulated, most email servers will flag email sent from PHP as potential spam and most times will be blocked and not even sent to the junk folder. The fact that some mail gets through and others just disappear is because Spam traps set thresholds. Depending on the body text, subject line, type of links, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your theme have *mails* folder and have *password_query* mail templates in
   corresponding language folder.
2. Go to **Preferences > Customers**,  and check the value of password reset    delay. Make the delay value higher like 360 minutes.